# ASp.Net build configuration is always in Debug mode

Tags: asp.net, buildconfiguration

I developed a Solution in VS2005 for an ASP.net application which also has some class library projects that the ASP.Net project references. I have changed the Build Configuration of the solution to release but strangely, the ASP.net build config remains Debug whatever I do. This is weird as I see no reason why MS should have done that. Is it something else I could not thiink of?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a web application?  Is so, did you changed the web.config debug="True" attribute to debug="False"?

Comment: My first thought was the same. I heve eevn tried deleting the debug attrib but no luck.